# How to convert String to UTC timezone?

Tags: java, spring

I have a string like this,

```
String userTime = "12-09-2022 08:21:32 EST"
```

I have a utility which converts this string to UTC time

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(userTime, f).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

This returns the result `2022-12-09T12:21:32Z`

It gives back the time difference of 4 hours. Shouldn't it be 5 hours?

Comment: How did you check the output? I get 2022-12-09T13:21:32Z
https://ideone.com/3mGJDq

Comment: As @Noplopy mentioned, there's a timezone difference in October. I tried the date in December and it returned the date with 5 hour of difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a time change in EST timezone on October 30th, try in September and you have only 4 hours difference and 5 hours in December.

Your can try this on this website: https://savvytime.com/converter/est-to-utc/sep-12-2022/8-30am